VBA to connect to an MSAccess database on Sharepoint
I have developed an XLSM file which gets connected to an MS Access DB placed in a shared folder like \\Server\data\Service\Tool\MyApp\UAT\UAT MyApp DB.accdb and through the below function I do my job.
Public Function fGetConn() As ADODB.Connection 
    On Error Resume Next 
    DatabasePath= "\\Server\data\Service\Tool\MyApp\UAT\UAT MyApp DB.accdb" 
    If Cnx Is Nothing Or Cnx.Status = 0 Then 
        Set Cnx = New ADODB.Connection 
        With Cnx 
            .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" 
            .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & DatabasePath & ";Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=testpassword;" 
            .Open 
        End With 
    End If 
    Set fGetConn = Cnx 
End Function

The issue is now this MSAccess DB has been moved to the Sharepoint and I'm not able anymore to open the connection to this DB so I cannot edit any data.
Probably the issue can be solved by adding the shortcut to OneDrive but I would like to avoid this even If I'm sure OneDrive cannot manage any edit activity on MSAccess DB.
What should I do?

You cannot access an Acces database on Sharepoint or OneDrive because these are not shared via SMB.
What to do is to copy the database file to a local drive, use it as before, then - when done - copy it back to the Sharepoint folder.
